# How to make my c++ have setenv?

Tags: c++, mingw, msys, mingw-w64

These are messages I’ve got as I typed `./configure` of CMAKE-3.2.3 with MinGW64+MSYS.

```
CMake 3.2.3, Copyright 2000-2015 Kitware, Inc.
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc
C++ compiler on this system is: g++
Makefile processor on this system is: make
g++ is GNU compiler
g++ does not have setenv
g++ does not have unsetenv
g++ has environ in stdlib.h
```

Then I’ve got tow messages, in `Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log` when `./configure` aborted ,which might be related to above messages.

These are messages in `cmake_bootstrap.log`

```
c:/src/products/oss/cmake-3.2.3/Source/kwsys/kwsysPlatformTestsCXX.cxx:4
33:28: error: 'setenv' was not declared in this scope^M"
c:/src/products/oss/cmake-3.2.3/Source/kwsys/kwsysPlatformTestsCXX.cxx:4
41:15: error: 'unsetenv' was not declared in this scope^M"
```

Now my question is,

How can I make my c++ have `setenv` and `unsetenv`?

Does anyone know which version of C++ has `setenv` and `unsetenv`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `stdlib.h`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```